# Partial inheritance - Share Primitive Values between Objects

Tags: javascript, prototype, primitive, ecmascript-5

I dindn't knew a better title, so to explain it,
lets say you have a 'constructor' which

- Instantiates an Object and sets some properties

  - In the process of Instatiation annother Object is created
  - This Objects prototype should shadow some of the properties from the first Object to his Children

So when the first Objects propertie `num` is changed The other Objects protype propertie `num`
should be changed too

This would of course work in the cases of `num` being

- wrapped in an Object
- a propertie/element of a non Primitive Object

But if `num` would be a Number or a String

The propertie of the protype wouldn't change if `num` would be overwritten in the first Object as Primitive vars are passed as value and not by reference,or if a propertie is an Object and will be overwritten with a new Object

**So my question is
are there any "neat" ways of being able to let an Object inherit Primitive values of Properties from another Object, and let them share one reference?**

Here is some example Code, you can skip the first one, its here for the completeness of the code

```
/* Inheritance Helper*/

var base = (function baseConstructor() {

  var obj = {
    create:function instantiation() {
        if(this != base) {
        var instance = Object.create(this.pub);
         this.init.apply(instance,arguments);
         this.instances.push(instance);
        return instance;
        } else {
          throw new Error("You can't create instances of base");
        }
    },
    inherit:function inheritation() {
      var sub = Object.create(this);
      sub.pub = Object.create(this.pub);
      sub.sup = this;
      return sub;
    },
    initclosure:function initiation() {},
    instances: [],
    pub: {}
    
  };
  
  
  
  Object.defineProperty(obj,"init",{
   set:function (fn) {
     if (typeof fn != "function")
       throw new Error("init has to be a function");
     if (!this.hasOwnProperty("initclosure"))      
       this.initclosure = fn;
    },
    get:function () {
        var that = this;
        //console.log(that)
            return function() {
              if(that.pub.isPrototypeOf(this)) //!(obj.isPrototypeOf(this) || that == this))
                that.initclosure.apply(this,arguments);
              else
                throw new Error("init can't be called directly"); 
             };
    }    
     
  });
  
  
  Object.defineProperty(obj,"create",{configurable:false,writable:false});
    Object.defineProperty(obj,"inherit",{configurable:false,writable:false});
  return obj;
})();

/*Helpers*/
function merge (obj) {
 if(arguments.length < 2)
   throw new Error({msg:"At least 2 parameters needed"});
  for ( var i = 1, ilen = arguments.length;i < ilen; i++)
   for (var k in arguments[i])
     obj[k] = arguments[i][k];
}

/*Helpers for workarounds*/
function tieProp (prop,obj) {
  if(arguments.length < 3)
    throw new Error({msg:"At least 2 Objects are needed"});
  var ref = obj[prop];
  
  for ( var i = 1,ilen = arguments.length;i<ilen;i++)
      Object.defineProperty(arguments[i],prop,{
      set: function (val) {
        ref = val;
      },
      get: function () {
        return ref;
      }
    });

}
```

So, this is the part where the Objects are created

```
/*Example Code*/

var Series = base.inherit();
Series.init = function (specs) {
  var _Series = this;
      specs = specs ||{};

  this.seasons = [];
  
  var Season = Series.inherit();
  Season.init = function(specs) {
    var _Season = this;
        specs = specs || {};
    _Series.seasons.push(this);
    
    merge(this,specs);  
   
        
        
  };
  
  merge(this,specs);
  Season.pub.score = this.score; // First way
  Season.pub.stats = this.stats; // Second Way
  tieProp("scoreTied",this,Season.pub); //Third Way
  Season.pub.scoreSetter = this.scoreSetter; // Second Way
  
    this.updateScore = function (score) { // Forth Way
      this.scoreSetter = score;
      Season.pub.scoreSetter = score;
  };
  tieProp("someObj",this,Season.pub); //Obj Example
  
  this.addSeason = function (specs)  {
    Season.create(specs);
  };
  

};
Series.pub.toString = function () {
 return this.title + " has  a score of " + this.scoreTied ;
};


var Futurama = Series.create({
  title:"Futurama",
  score:1, // 1.
  scoreTied:2, // 2.
  stats:{ //3.
    score:3
  },
  scoreSetter:4,
  someObj:{a:"b"}
});
Futurama.addSeason();
```

And lets log the console output before we change a propertie

```
console.log("BeforeChange",Futurama.score + " - " + Futurama.seasons[0].score); //"1 - 1"
console.log(Futurama.scoreTied + " - " + Futurama.seasons[0].scoreTied); // "2 - 2"
console.log(Futurama.stats.score +  " - " + Futurama.seasons[0].stats.score); // "3 - 3"
console.log(Futurama.scoreSetter +  " - " + Futurama.seasons[0].scoreSetter); //"4 - 4"
console.log(JSON.stringify(Futurama.someObj) + " - " + JSON.stringify(Futurama.seasons[0].someObj));  //"{"a":"b"} - {"a":"b"}"
```

Then change the score properties of `Futurama`

```
Futurama.score = 2; //TFirst way // This will fail
Futurama.scoreTied = 3; //Second way
Futurama.stats.score = 4; // Third way 
Futurama.updateScore(5); // Forth Way
Futurama.someObj = {b:"a"}; // Object replacement
```

And log them

```
console.log("After Change",Futurama.score + " - " + Futurama.seasons[0].score); // 2 - 1
console.log(Futurama.scoreTied + " - " + Futurama.seasons[0].scoreTied); // 3 - 3
console.log(Futurama.stats.score +  " - " + Futurama.seasons[0].stats.score); //4 -4 
  console.log(Futurama.scoreSetter +  " - " + Futurama.seasons[0].scoreSetter); //5 - 5
console.log(JSON.stringify(Futurama.someObj) + " - " + JSON.stringify(Futurama.seasons[0].someObj)) ; //"{"b":"a"} - {"b":"a"}"
```

So, this would be possible when either using

- Object.defineProperty to provide the properties with getters and setters

*like in     `function tieProp (prop,obj) {...`*

But i don't know if using Object.defineProperty would be an appropriate in this kind of situation and  do i really have to set propertie descriptors to let some properties share one reference to a primitive value?

- Wrapping all primitive values in an Object which will be passed as reference and change this Objects propertie

*like in `Season.pub.stats = this.stats; // Second Way`*

This would be ok, but I'm not that comfortable with this, because i'd have to move properties into another, which kind of takes away some of the naming freedom and in this example, i'd like `score` as the score of Futurama to be in `Futurama.score` rather then in `Futurama.stats.score`

*writing setters for the properties, which simply sets both values of the Objects

*like in  `this.updateScore = function (score) { // Forth Way` *

But i would rather like to stay away from this, as i would have to add methods to the Object

I don't know if i simply shouldn't do something like this at all or if I'm just missing a
really simple way of doing this ??

any suggestions or pointings in the right direction would be really appreciated

and thanks in advance for answers and the patience to read through this

Heres a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ayiqaw/1/edit) to fiddle around with

Comment: +1 for putting so much detail into your question!

Answer (score 0):

Use a named function as the property value to share instances of atomic elements:

```
foo = {"1":1}
bar = {"1": function baz() { return foo["1"] } }

foo["1"] = 2;
foo["1"] === bar["1"]();
```

**References**

- [Simulating Tracepoints in Chrome Dev Tools](http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2015-08-30-simulating-tracepoints-in-chrome-dev-tools.html)
- [Practical Applications of Partial Application](http://raganwald.com/2013/01/05/practical-applications-of-partial-application.html)